# Interpret parameter in bash script

Tags: bash

I have the following bash file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "$1"
cmdcopy="kubectl get nodes -o json | jq -c '.items[] | select(.status.nodeInfo.osImage | contains(\"$1\"))' | jq -r .metadata.name"                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
echo $cmdcopy

old_nodes=`kubectl get nodes -o json | jq -c '.items[] | select(.status.nodeInfo.osImage | contains("$1"))' | jq -r .metadata.name`
echo $old_nodes

for node in $old_node
echo 'Doing something to $node'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
done
```

If I run outside the result of cmdcopy, it all works good.
But inside the script the result of echo $old_nodes is empty.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: Stay clear of legacy backtick-based command substitution syntax -- the modern `$()` form has fewer pitfalls (one of which is a change in how backslashes are interpreted within them).

Comment: What do you mean by "run outside the result of cmdcopy"?

Comment: (and `for node in $old_node` runs afoul of [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor))

Comment: Also, `contains("$1")` isn't going to be interpreted inside single quotes. Use `jq --arg` to pass arguments from bash to jq; don't substitute data into code. (That's not just jq advice; substituting data into code is bad form in pretty much _any_ language).